# Can't resolve the second promise on Facebook JS with Angular

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, angularjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm developing an application with Facebook JS and AngularJS. First of all I login and then get the Friends and show them in a list. Everything is working fine with this code:

```
var friendsController = app.controller(
    "FriendsController",
    function FriendsController($scope, friendsData, $location, $routeParams)
    {
        $scope.friendsData = friendsData.data;
        $scope.params = $routeParams;

        $scope.onClickFriend = function(friendId)
        {
            $location.path("friends/friend:" + friendId);
        }
    }
);

friendsController.loadFriends = function($q, $rootScope)
{
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    FB.api("/me/friends?fields=name,picture.type(square)", function(response)
    {
        $rootScope.$apply(deferred.resolve(response));
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Now I want to load the details of a friend in a new view, so I create a new `routeProvider` rule with a new controller and a new promise.

```
var friendDetailController = app.controller(
    "FriendDetailController",
    function FriendDetailController($scope, friendData, $routeParams)
    {
        $scope.friendData = friendData;
        $scope.params = $routeParams;

        console.log(friendData);
    }
);

friendDetailController.loadFriend = function($q, $route, $rootScope)
{
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var friendUrl = $route.current.params.friendId.split(":")[1] + "?fields=id,name,picture.type(large)";

    FB.api("/" + friendUrl, function(response)
    {
        $rootScope.$apply(deferred.resolve(response));
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

The problem is that I'm entering at `loadFriend` but it seems that it's not making the call to the FB.api, and it's really weird because it is working on `FriendsController`, which is basically the same.

In fact, it seems that is the second call the one that is not called, because if I invert the calls (first `FriendDetail`, afterwards, Friends), `FriendDetail` is working.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. Did you get it fixed?

Comment: Well, at the end I decided to develop the backend with NodeJS because I think that the Facebook API is really buggy with AngularJS :S

Comment: Thank you. Your question has a solution which works and returns promise allowing to add some flow to my page.